# Single word for representing a person who guides at right time

Tags: single-word-requests

Please help me finding the single word for representing a person who guides at right time (at the time of need).

Comment: are you actually translating something from a different language to English? What is the context, may I know?

Comment: could you give an example sentence where you would use this word? I cannot quite understand what the meaning of your word is.

Comment: I don't think the single word you want exists. All the words we have for *guide*, *mentor* etc. are not specific about what moment the guidance is given. You know, in English it's OK to use more than one word!

Answer (score 2):

but not *guide* I take it, how about *mentor*, *advisor*, *counsellor* or, depending on how much guidance and how much need, even *savior*

Comment: Hi Jim, Thank you for your response. The person I want to represent is the one who guide in the time of need. The advice will actually throws the light on the state of the person who is receiving.

Comment: +1 Well sorry Jim, I haven't seen mentor in your answer. I am deleting mine.

Comment: @Jim wont you like to add something that is an antonym for anachronism?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a character in a story, I refer you to Joseph Campbell’s theory of the [monomyth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomyth), which posits that there is a seventeen stage template that underpins well-known narratives from around the world.

The “person who guides at the right time” shows up at the third stage of the journey.  (Think Obi-Wan Kenobi in *Star Wars* or Giles in *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*.)  This character is usually referred to as the *mentor*.

Comment: or Al in Quantum Leap :)

Comment: I would go for mentor - as a person who ofers timely and appropriate advice. It is probably the closest single English word.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you may use **godsend**, if context is suitable.

> Godsend: something wanted or needed that comes or happens unexpectedly.

Comment: Too vague. A motorway service station just as you're craving a coffee can be described as a *godsend*.

Comment: @slim: that's not a godsend?

Comment: @Mitch a coffee when you really need one is a godsend. It's not an adviser though, is it?

Comment: @slim: oh. right. So godsend might work but is too inclusive/sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

A **guardian angel** is one who looks over you and helps you in time of need.

But that is more of, when things go wrong, having you step aside to avoid disaster rather than giving advice to make your own choice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *[providence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/providence)*.  As a noun its senses include "the careful guardianship exercised by a deity" and "a manifestation of divine care or direction" and it is sometimes used to refer to the agent providing the help or guidance.  Its adjectival form *providential* has a sense of fortunate or serendipitous, hence of occurring unexpectedly but at an appropriate time.  That is, *providence* does not denote timely guidance, but has some overtones of such.